# Getting "The resource cannot be found. " error trying to load Glimpse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have an existing MVC3 project (upgraded from MVC2 about 3 months ago) and then added Glimpse via NuGet yesterday. When I ran (hit F5) it, and go to http://localhost:8888/Glimpse/Config what I got is error for "Server Error in '/' Application" - The resource cannot be found.

[image]

I have tried creating a brand new MVC3 project and adding Glimpse via NuGet in there and it works. My global.asax is exactly the same line by line and so is my web.config.

According to ELMAH, the dll for Glimpse is found and executed properly, but since it's not inheriting from IController so it breaks. Here is a screen shot from ELMAH:

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a HttpModule that listens for requests that are *Glimpse/*? If the HttpModule is loaded then it should handle the request long before MVC tries to resolve "Glimpse" as a controller.

If you are getting the error you are it would seem that maybe something is wrong with your config. Can you compare your config in your sample project that works to the real project that doesn't to make sure all the registrations have come across.

If everything looks fine there, the next thing is that the config is right but the HttpModule is not being registered. To do the registration we are using:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(...)
```

See http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/27/dynamicmoduleutility.aspx for more.

Given that you upgraded your solution I would say maybe its something here. To be sure though, if you aren't able to track it down, any chance that you can send us a cut down version of your solution that has the same problem?

Lastly, are you doing anything "out of the norm"? Specifically are using a different view engine, or custom dependency resolver, etc?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary (using aspx engine, no IoC, etc), pretty straight forward project with CSLA middle tier. I will try to take a look at HttpModule.

Comment: I ended up making a new project shell and migrating over my code - and it works now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not a problem... if you ever find out what the difference was please let us know.

Comment: Any idea what fixed this? I am at a loss trying to get it to work.

Comment: @Jason No idea really. My guess is that the project settings between a legacy MVC2 upgrade & a new MVC3 project is a bit different. The diff may not matter much to VS 2010, but somehow it matters for Glimpse - at least in the references part.

Comment: I figured it out on my end. I was just going to the wrong URL.. I had my app running from a virtual directory, so I needed to include the virtual in the path, rather than trying to access it through the default website.

Comment: /glimpse.axd worked for me for turning on Glimpse (MVC3 + ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, turns out my problem was that I had removed the Castle.Core and Castle.DynamicProxy references. I did an

```
Uninstall-Package Glimpse 
Uninstall-Package Castle.Core
Uninstall-Package Castle.DynamicProxy
```

followed by

```
Install-Package Glimpse
```

From the package manager console and it sorted itself.

Comment: With mine, it has no Castle (or any DI for that matter).

Comment: @Johannes That could be your problem then, Glimpse depends on Castle. Try removing any reference to Castle from your packages.config and reinstall Glimpse as above.

Comment: I don't think so. In a BRAND NEW project with MVC3, it works fine without any reference to Castle or any DI.

Comment: That's very strange Johannes, I just checked there and installing Glimpse in a brand new MVC 3 project, definitely brings down Castle and adds references to it, here's the output from the Package Manager console http://pastebin.com/uT4cdvPq

Comment: Just so you guys, come release 0.81 onwards the planning to remove the Nuget and dll dependencies on Castle... It should just be one dll and one package. Hopefully this will help in these cases.

Comment: Weird. If I try now, it get the 0.81. But on my old project (which was fresh MVC3 when it was created - which worked), there is no reference to Castle in.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.83, Glimpse no longer uses the config/config (or any glimpse/*) URL.

Instead, please go to Glimpse.axd to change your Glimpse settings.

Comment: I'm getting a 'resource not found' on the axd url